# Possibility to detect if Quest headset is mounted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a function in XR that can be triggered to check if the headset is worn by the user or is lying idle?
Would like to know if such a function exists in Quest devices.

Earlier for Oculus, it was done this way:

```
if (!OVRPlugin.userPresent && m_wasUserPresent){
 
}
```

or in OVRManager.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Occurs when an HMD is put on the user's head.
/// </summary>
public static event Action HMDMounted;

/// <summary>
/// Occurs when an HMD is taken off the user's head.
/// </summary>
public static event Action HMDUnmounted;
```